# PHPMailler with mandrill smtp gives connection error

Tags: php, email, smtp, mandrill

I am using smtp by mandrill on my website through PHPMailer. I have configured everything correctly. Here are the configurations-

```
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "smtp.mandrillapp.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "smtp.mandrillapp.com"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 587;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "MANDRILL_USERNAME"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "MANDRILL_KEY";
```

When I send email, it gives an error `SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)`

I am using godaddy shared hosting plan.
Please help.

Comment: You may want to change your port by your needs - [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15796888/2600397)  - Just be sure

Comment: I have checked with port 25 but still its not working. Tried port 465 with ssl type encryption but it didn't work as well

Answer (score 2):

Some shared hosting providers block all outbound SMTP connections or common SMTP ports. You'll need to contact GoDaddy to confirm whether you're on a plan that supports outbound SMTP connections (you'll typically need a higher-level or VPS plan to support this with most shared hosts).

Comment: I believe thats the reason. Thanks a lot.