# How to send an email with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

What is the process for sending an email using python. What I found in my research was either different than what I was attempting or didn't work when I attempted to actually use it. This doesn't seem like it would be a complicated task.

Comment: What are you using to send it? Google's api, Microsofts?

Comment: I am using python?

Comment: What libraries are you importing for this? At the top of your code, when you write `import ...`, what is it that you're importing? Also - you need (i) to explain the exact problem you're having and any errors you get, and (ii) to attach an example of your code or this question is going to very quickly get  down voted or closed.

Comment: You need an SMTP server, yes. Gmail, for example is commonly used.

Comment: I need someone to teach me, I am not using anything right now, it was just I need to know so I can make a project in the future.

Comment: Read this to get a little idea http://stackabuse.com/how-to-send-emails-with-gmail-using-python/

Comment: SO is not a coding service. If you don’t know how to program, I’d suggest google for free tutorials and watch YouTube videos.

Comment: @Saleem I am not asking for you to code for me. I know how to code. I just wanted to know where to start in this whole pretty complicated process

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I made it in python3.6.3 and after that I rebuilt the code to python3.2.6 but it works. :)

First of all we gonna import few things which are in a standard Python library.

```
import smtplib
from getpass import getpass
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
```

---

> Tip!
>   If you want to send email from gmail you have to enable less-secure
>   app: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

---

We have to make an email so:

```
sender = 'example_sender@gmail.com'
receiver = 'example_receiver@gmail.com'

content = """The receiver will see this message.
            Best regards"""

msg = MIMEText(content)
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = receiver
msg['Subject'] = 'Simple app script'
```

---

> Tip! Of course you can also read content for example from file by using:
>
> ```
> with open('/path/to/your/file', 'r') as file:
>     content = file.read()
> ```

---

Now we can handle a "magic" server side.

---

> Tip! Server name you can easily found in your email settings. (IMAP/POP
>   page) 
>   Here you have a list of servers I've found:
>   https://www.arclab.com/en/kb/email/list-of-smtp-and-pop3-servers-mailserver-list.html

---

The solution for gmail, but you it can work with any server:

```
smtp_server_name = 'smtp.gmail.com'
#port = '465' # for secure messages
port = '587' # for normal messages
```

---

> Tip! There are answers for difference of these ports:
>   [What is the difference between ports 465 and 587?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796530/what-is-the-difference-between-ports-465-and-587)

---

I think this sample of code is simply. By smtplib.SMTP_SSL we can only handle server by secure port (465). In other case we use different method.

```
if port == '465':
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('{}:{}'.format(smtp_server_name, port))
else :
    server = smtplib.SMTP('{}:{}'.format(smtp_server_name, port))
    server.starttls() # this is for secure reason

server.login(sender, getpass(prompt="Email Password: "))
server.send_message(msg)
server.quit()
```

When server is going to login you have to type your password after prompt in your shell.

And that's it. I ran this on Linux from command line.

Please feel free to ask for questions! :)

PS. I tested it on Windows 7 on fresh install of python 3.2.2. Everything works.

Comment: this looks like it will work, I will test it when I get home.

Comment: I got this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python32/email.py", line 1, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "C:\Python32\lib\smtplib.py", line 47, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "C:/Python32\email.py", line 3, in <module>
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
ImportError: No module named mime.text

Comment: Yes it works. I tried on Windows 7, fresh install of python 3.2.2. And I got  a message to my email. :) Try to reinstall python or simply install new version.

Comment: @Iszpiczakowski I am on windows 10