# How to properly escape Email header in php

Tags: php, email

I have the following php code

```
<?php 
$from = $_POST['email'];
$to = "myaddr@myserver.com";
$subject = "new message";
$message = "new message from ". $_POST['email'] ." >>> " .  $_POST['message'];
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
```

?>

I just started php, so this is the result of copying. I suspect this of being vulnerable, because one could probably just insert a newline char in the email adress field and rewrite my whole mail header for me.

How do I properly escape this? 
And while you're at it - do you see any other mistakes/vulns?

Comment: One possibility might be to look at libraries like Swiftmailer and learn from the source. I _think_ PHP does protect against header injection, but I _think_ you need to specify `$headers` as an array for that to work. Not sure though!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but many spam filters will filter out emails with a "from" that's not actually allowed to come from the server sending the email.  So, you should probably set it to "something@myserver.com" and set the "Reply-To:" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add email validation:

```
if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    //send mail after validation
    mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you should make sure the mail server that your script is connecting to is properly secured. If the script is connecting to a remote smtp host first, then it should ensure that the remote smtp host is secured.

Usually email servers are configured so the email submission occurs over a secure ssl encrypted channel.

Secure email servers accept smtp mail submission over ports 465 and 587. These ports are secure smtp ports and are supported by most email servers. [What is the difference between ports 465 and 587?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796530/what-is-the-difference-between-ports-465-and-587)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I used to filter the email address and add it as a "Reply-to" header:

```php
$filtered_email = filter_var(trim($email), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$headers = 'From: system@myserver.com' . "\r\n";
if ( $filtered_email ) {
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $filtered_email . "\r\n";
}
```

The documentation for `filter_var` says that it may return `false` if it failed so I put it in an `if` statement (also should deal with it being an empty string).

As I said in a comment, spam filters may prevent your email from reaching its destination if the "From:" is an address that's not the server it was sent from, so it's best to use the "Reply-To:" instead.