# Python Send a message to domain-based email

Tags: python, email, smtp

Trying to send email message using python's smtplib via gmail:

```
import smtplib

msg = "\r\n".join([
    "From: " + email_host,
    "To: " + email_recipient,
    "Subject: subject",
    "",
    email_msg
])
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(email_host, email_pwd)
server.sendmail(email_host, email_recipient, msg)
server.quit()
```

For popular services such as yandex, yahoo and gmail it works perfect. But it's impossible to send a message to domain-based emails (login@some_domain.com).

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, searching for the answer, I found out that Google Mail service doesn't allow to send messages to domain-based emails via 587 SMTP port, because it requires to use TLS.

[image]

I decided to switch onto 465 SMTP port as said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796530/what-is-the-difference-between-ports-465-and-587) post, so it works now perfect! Also, for testing purposes, I used another Mail Service (Yandex), which supports only 465 SMTP port - it works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Email services apply restrictions since there's no authentication when you're sending those emails.

E.g.
https://support.asperasoft.com/hc/en-us/articles/216128488-How-to-use-Gmail-as-an-SMTP-relay-for-notification-testing

> This SMTP server does not require TLS or authentication. It is
>   restricted because emails can only be sent to other Gmail addresses or
>   Google apps users--therefore it may only make sense for testing within
>   an internal network that uses Gmail or Google apps. Limits apply per
>   recipient.

I.e. these services don't mind sending emails within their own domain, but don't want malicious users sending to other domains.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot send a message to domain-based email via smtp gmail. How to find out solution?

Comment: depends on the service, but for example gmail will require authentication if you want to use their SMTP server: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en . Namely: "Your full Gmail or G Suite email address is required for authentication." and "Port 465 (SSL required)    Port 587 (TLS required)    Dynamic IPs allowed"