# Laravel sending email got 421

Tags: laravel, smtp

I have problem with my laravel project. before, my project can sending email. but now, email not working. I get problem

> Expected response code 220 but got code "421", with message "421 5.7.1
>   Connection refused "

I have using smtp Gmail, and another smtp from my client but same.
this is my env

[image]

I hope, sending email in my project can working again.

Comment: Try to use port `465`.

Comment: @rkg 465 port for gmail or another smtp mail server? and what is 465 ?

Comment: Port *465* is for **smtps**. SSL encryption is started automatically before any SMTP level communication. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796530/what-is-the-difference-between-ports-465-and-587).

Comment: hello @rkg , i have tested to use port 465, but not working

Answer (score 0):

.env should look like

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=abc@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=**************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue until I removed the # from the password.  I know, it shouldn't be like that but hey, it solved it for me...

Answer (score 0):

All looks good. But one issue it could be is that your password has characters in it that .env file see's as some executable code. For example in [Rod Chadwick's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62391748/11592836) answer. A `#` means inline documentation. Which pritty sure was the reason for his error.

Url encoding is what you should use for your password. And maybe also for your username. You can url encode online here: https://www.urlencoder.org/