# How do I send mails from a self managed Gitlab server?

Tags: docker, gitlab

Thats a part of my Docker-Compose File. The problem is that the mails dont reach the users. Does someone knows why?

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  web:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'rainws02.tjema.local'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'https://rainws02.rain.local'
        gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
        gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "rainex01.rain.local"
        gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 465
        gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "gitlab@rainlocal"
        gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "PASSWORD"
        gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "rain.local"
        gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
        gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
        gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false
        gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'peer'
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = "gitlab@rain.local"
...
```

Comment: do the mails reached the smtp server?

Comment: I dont know. 
I tested if my Exchange Server is able to send mail -  and he is. Where can I check if they reach the server?

Comment: have you checked exchange server logs? are the email receivers uses the same smtp server? you can test whether docker sends mail or not by setting up dummy server (e.g. FakeSMTP) somewhere reachable then see if it actually emitting smtp requests. there are many ways to lose mails..

Comment: The users are on the same SMPT-Server.
Just checked the logs. I cant see any mail, from gitlab@rain.local.
I wanted to ask if there is a mistake in my docker-compose?

Comment: i checked gitlab docs, it says [port should be 587](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/smtp.html#microsoft-exchange-with-authentication), not 465. it also match with [microsoft's docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/deployment-ref/network-ports?view=exchserver-2019).

Comment: It also says 25. Do u know the diffrence?

Comment: 25 for unauthenticated one

Comment: I tested Port 587... sadly no diffrence.
Apparently you can test it with the command:
Notify.test_email('destination_email@address.com', 'Message Subject', 'Message Body').deliver_now

But I get an error: 
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `'test@rain.local','

Comment: I just tested it again in de rails console and the folowing error appeared:
 (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (self signed certificate))

Comment: [25 = SMTP, 465 - SMTPS *or* rendezvous for SSM, and 587 = SMTP-MSA.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15796530/1256452)

Comment: (In any case, the "correct" setup depends on how you choose to set up your mail service. There may be some Git*Lab* standard for this, but *Git* doesn't pick one. I updated your tag.)

Comment: You've specified `gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = false` but are using a port number typically reserved for connections with TLS enabled. I would recommend trying to either (1) enable TLS (or use `gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true`) or (2) use port 25 if you are sure you are not using SSL/TLS.