# Google disabled access to less secure apps

Tags: python, email, flask, smtp, flask-mail

With google having disabled the access to enable access to less secure apps can anyone suggest ways in which I can send mails using flask-mail? It has to be disabled in the mail account I'm using to send mails using flask-mail.

[image: No option to enable or disable]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'd be curious to know more details on this issue, can you please post any exceptions you are seeing on the flask server when trying this?

Comment: Hi @alex, have you managed to solve this issue? I just encountered the same issue after Google disable less secure app access. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is about google security  you can use app password instead of your account password in MAIL_PASSWORD configuration, To do that  you should enable 2-step verification in your Google Account and then use app password,
So go to your Google Account,

Security

Signing in to Google

Enable 2-step verification

App password

Make app password and use it as your MAIL_PASSWORD

In link below you can see other options

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en&utm_source=google-account&utm_medium=profile-less-secure-apps-card

Comment: But for 2 step verification, we need to provide the phone number right... I want to send using a dummy account. Any way to send without using 2-factor thing?

Comment: Well I think Your app must be more secure and meet google security standards, or you can use other email client server

Answer (score 0):

- so you need to set up the App Password from setting.
- This video shows how to set up App Password = [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BFTCVC33qhQ&t=374s).

setps:

**1. Manage your Google Account**

**2. Goto the Security. on left side**

**3.At security->Signing in to Google**

1 first need on 2-setp-verfication.

2 then click App Password.then select app and device.

```
for me app=Mail.

device=Windows Compter.
```

3 A password is genrated. copy the password. It only show one time

**4 used this password to login.**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using sendmail and ESMTP with Google Mail,
and the excellent 'sender_based_routing' patch from:
[http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~rickert/cf/](http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/%7Erickert/cf/)
which allows sendmail to choose a different relay based on
email 'From:' headers; using my MS-365 corporate email selects
smtp.outlook365.com , while using my personal email selects
smtp.google.com.

Because I am out of mobile phone coverage while at home, I cannot
enable 2-Factor authentication or use an App Token, which requires
2-factor authentication and the ability to receive SMS; my
mobile phone package does not include SMS-over-WiFi, and
Google's 2-factor Auth SMS messages are not sent over Google Chat SMS.

The only workaround I have found is to open a new Google WorkSpaces
email account, then you can enable the SMTP relay feature, and
sending email with sendmail + ESMTP then works again.

Google has thus doubled its revenue stream from me; and since I must copy every message sent by my new account to my old one,
it has  doubled my storage requirements, that I pay for.
Clever Google! Never neglects an opportunity to squeeze more
profit from its users.

Anyway, paying for 2 email accounts in order to send emails is
vastly preferable to be being forced to use the horrible GMail
GUI - I can use MA/GNUS Emacs to send mails - definitely worth it.

The best long term solution, which I will do as soon as I can,
is setup one's own Email server , and scrap use of Google altogether - I wish I was in a position to do this, as soon as
I am I will - it requires a static IP and an always-on server.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Before proceeding please enable 2 factor authentication.

Less secure apps (https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/lesssecureapps) is no longer available.

We can use apppasswords feature provided by google via following link
https://myaccount.google.com/u/0/apppasswords

Check below image for reference, Use 16 digit code provided by google in-place of password.

[image]